# How come AFC Championship become a "洲际比赛”

Tags: meaning

"洲际" literally means between continents or intercontinental, but AFC Championship is a competition staged by the Asian Football Confederation, the governing body of Asian football, with participating teams from within Asia, so it could be a continent-wise contest, but absolutely not an intercontinental championship.

But most of Chinese media, including CCTV, the national official broadcaster talked about the AFC Championship matches of Guangzhou Evergrande vs other Asian rivals as "洲际比赛". Would it be appropriate to introduce such games as "洲级比赛"?

Comment: 洲级 seems to have low usage frequency (e.g. jukuu has no sample containing 洲级) it is used for ICBM 洲际弹道导弹, 州级 "national, statewide" occurs more often

Answer (score 2):

Because the member countries are not just located in the Asian continent now.

The Asian Football Confederation includes Australia (Oceania) and the Oceanian island of Guam, a territory of the United States.

洲级比赛 is not very common.

Answer (score 0):

I think AFC Championship should be translated to "亚俱杯".

Answer (score 0):

AFC in Chinese is 亚足联冠军联赛 or in short 亚冠联赛/亚冠
洲际比赛 means games between continents
And AFC have countries like Australia, which is not a Asian country. So AFC became a 洲级比赛
2007赛季开始加入澳大利亚的俱乐部。[--Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9A%E8%B6%B3%E8%81%94%E5%86%A0%E5%86%9B%E8%81%94%E8%B5%9B)